# Perform a dbt pivot on multiple string columns

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I'm trying to perform a pivot in dbt with on multiple columns based on a single one.
For example, suppose I have the following table:

| Project name | Main Color | RGB | HEX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| project A | blue | 171, 218, 252 | ACACDE |
| project B | blue | 172, 172, 222 | ABDAFC |
| project A | red | 184, 51, 106 | B8336A |

and I want to obtain:

| Main Color | RGB_blue | HEX_blue | RGB_red | HEX_red |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| project A | 171, 218, 252 | ACACDE | 184, 51, 106 | B8336A |
| project B | 172, 172, 222 | ABDAFC | NULL | NULL |

then how should I proceed?
I've had a look at [dbt_utils.pivot()](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#pivot-source), but it seems like aggregations won't work with string values like the one I presented in the tables (I get a "`Numeric value '171, 218, 252' is not recognized`" error).

Plus, I need to pivot the original table using multiple columns as value (e.g. RGB and HEX), while the examples I've seen are limited to a single column.